# Perl's %ENV doesn't works in one-liner

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, solaris

I write simple bash line that should replace the LOGIN word in some bash script (will replace the word LOGIN to admin word)
But it doesn’t work?

But when I type bash command  on my Linux/solaris machine and then run separately the commands then its work

so why the bash one liner not work ( what’s the diff here ? )

bash one liner line

```
/tmp ROOT > bash -c 'export LOGIN=admin  ; /usr/local/bin/perl -i -pe 's/LOGIN/$ENV{LOGIN}/' /tmp/pass_login.bash'
ENV: Undefined variable.
```

run command separately under bash shell ( works fine )

```
/tmp ROOT >  bash
bash-3.2#    export LOGIN=admin
bash-3.2#    /usr/local/bin/perl -i -pe 's/LOGIN/$ENV{LOGIN}/' /tmp/pass_login.bash
```

.

my script

```
 more pass_login.bash


 #!/bin/bash

 MY_LOG_NAME=LOGIN
```

Comment: the error in the question - ENV: Undefined variable

Comment: If would be great if you replace the title of your question with a more self-explaining one.

Comment: To insert `'` into a `'` literal in `bash`, you can use `'\''`. e.g. `bash -c 'echo '\''$foo'\''; echo bar'` has `bash` execute `echo '$foo'; echo bar'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look to me like you have your quotes/variables escaped properly. Try this instead:

```
bash -c 'export LOGIN=admin  ; /usr/local/bin/perl -i -pe "s/LOGIN/\$ENV{LOGIN}/" /tmp/pass_login.bash'
```